# How do you access inner relations in rails active association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations

I have my associates set up in this manner.

event - (has_many) - vendor - (has_many) - product - (has_many) - productTags - (belongs_to) - tags

I'm trying to retrieve an array of tags for an event but only including those tags that have products.

Initially I have access to the event model through

```
@event = Event.find(1)
```

I'm having a really hard time going down the rabbit hole of associations to retrieve just the array of tags for all products.

Any help or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  def tags
    Tag.includes(:product_tags => {:product => {:vendor => {:event => {}}}}).where(["events.id = ?", self.id])
  end

end

@event = Event.find(1)
@event.tags
```

Comment: .includes can be replaced with .joins

Comment: +1 good answer. You can simplify the hash passed to `includes` (or `joins`) to: `:product_tags => {:product => {:vendor => :event }}`.